# ALSA, avoiding capture of sound before app starts

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm working on an app that captures audio using the ALSA API.

A tester of the app noticed the following behavior. If a sound is playing
just before the app starts, and then the app is started, that sound
is captured when `snd_pcm_readi()` is called. Any sound playing within
about a second before starting the app is captured in this way.

Is this behavior expected?

What I want the app to do is capture only the sound that occurs after the
application starts. How can I assure that happens (`snd_pcm_drop()`, maybe?).

Comment: What capture device is being used? A hardware loopback would not have latency, so I guess this is something like PulseAudio?

Comment: It's the "default" device which is, as you suggest, the "PulseAudio Sound Server".

Comment: I've tried using "sysdefault" instead, which appears to be the hardware device, but I get an error that the device is busy. Same thing if I use "hw:0,0".

Comment: Do you actually want to capture the played sound after your app has started?

Comment: I want to capture the played sound just at the time it's played.

Comment: If your hardware does not have a loopback routing, you must use some software like PulseAudio.